# Separate Paragraph into lines

Tags: ruby

Say I had this paragraph...

```
Before you can begin to determine what the composition of a particular paragraph will be. you must first decide on an argument and a working thesis statement for your paper. What is the most important idea that you are trying to convey to your reader. The information in each paragraph must be related to that idea. In other words. your paragraphs should remind your reader that there is a recurrent relationship between your thesis and the information in each paragraph. A working thesis functions like a seed from which your paper. and your ideas, will grow. The whole process is an organic one—a natural progression from a seed to a full-blown paper where there are direct, familial relationships between all of the ideas in the paper.
```

What code would I us so that it would separate this paragraph into separate lines? Like so...

```
Before you can begin to determine what the composition of a particular paragraph will be.

you must first decide on an argument and a working thesis statement for your paper. 

What is the most important idea that you are trying to convey to your reader. 

The information in each paragraph must be related to that idea. 

In other words. 

your paragraphs should remind your reader that there is a recurrent relationship between 
your thesis and the information in each paragraph.

A working thesis functions like a seed from which your paper. 

and your ideas, will grow.

The whole process is an organic one—a natural progression from a seed to a full-blown paper where there are direct, familial relationships between all of the ideas in the paper.
```

I was thinking of using gsub but I think its impossible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean into separate sentences?

Comment: Why would gsub be impossible? `sParagraphicalForm.gsub(/([^\s\w'"\-])/, "$1\n")` should get you moving in the right direction. If that's too aggressive, you could try, `sParagraphicalForm.gsub(/([\.!\?])/, "$1\n")` And then if you wanted that in an array, just call `.chomp` on the return string.

Comment: What about questions!?! That are really angry!!!! Or confused???? (plus not everyone uses capitals or periods anyway)

Comment: Addressing @tadman's comment, he makes a good point, and you might want to put `([^\s\w'"\-]+)` or `([\.!\?])` as your matching group, or if you wanted to play around with [hamiljs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149005/2694511), that would be `(?<=[\.|?\!])+\s*`. Of course, as tadman pointed out, not everyone uses proper punctuation, but short of implementing a natural-language processor, there isn't much to do about those cases other than classifying them as malformed input.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works.

```
.split(/(?<=[\.\?\!])\s*/).each { |i| puts i; puts '' }
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, but as a heads up `[\.|\?|\!]` should be `[\.\?\!]` or `(\.|\?|\!)`, as square-brackets do not support `|` as *or* in RegEx. That syntax is reserved for parenthetical groups. You also might not need to escape the `!`, but I am not 100% sure about that off the top of my head.

Comment: Good eye.  `[\.\?\!]` is where I was going.

Comment: You can use ``split(...).join("\n\n")`` if you want to have it return a single string with double line-breaks.

Comment: I like that even better.